# Group of order $35$ is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Ok so I'm reading Herstein's Algebra and there is a theorem that states that if $G$ is group of order $pq$ where $p,q$ are primes, $p>q$ and if $q$ doesn't divide $p-1$ then $G$ must be cyclic.

So this problem is basically special case and it is supposed to be proved same as the theorem. The part where I'm stuck at is why does $i^6-1=7k$ and $i^5-1=7m$ together with assumption that $q$ does not divide $p-1$ (in this case $5$ does not divide $7-1$), imply that $i$ is also congruent to $1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: That's Herstein.

Comment: There are only $7$ residues $\pmod 7$.  If you really cn't think of anything better, just try all $7$.  (Side note:  you only need $i^5\equiv 1 \pmod 7$)

Comment: If $i^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and $i^7 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ Then $i^7 i^{-6}  \cdots$